# Trace User Location whatever the state is In Use Foreground Background , Killed App react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, geolocation

I am developing an App which is related to employee management. I have to Send the employee location to the server after user click on attendance .location will send continuously using socket Io user is using app or not. If background will show notification about the running task.

I am using react native for app development.

I Install many libraries to achieve this task But did not find the solution.

Used react-native-location with rn-foreground-service It work sometime only in background not when using the app Or navigating through pages  because I think library is not maintained. deprecated.

IS this possible if yes should I have write Native code as no libraries available.

Comment: Even if you're using a foreground service (I'm assuming based on name its doing that correctly, it might not be), you still have to understand how Android works.  A foreground service is *less likely* to be killed for resources.  It still can be.  It also will still be subjected to Doze mode and other power restrictions.

Comment: Yes , The foreground service is not ideal in this situation instead background task will be optimistic as it consume low battery. Can you refer me some path, direction so Can read the docs and after understand start implementing. I have already lost my one week in this thanks for your precious time

Comment: No, in Android a Background service is killed off after 2 minutes in modern Android.  You want a foreground task.  Or preferably another OS-  what you're trying to do is explicitly something the OS is designed against doing.If it has to be Android, it will need to be a foreground service, actively whitelisting out of power management (which can't be done programmatically, must be done by the user) and it still won't be 100% reliable, because the OS really doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: So what's Is the best possible solution .should I run the service in the foreground and force user to not close the app rather minimize the app. I have seen one app named "xRecorder" in play store which is still open when I killed and their notification is appearing.

Comment: When user clock in. he will carry is mobile to different places . I don't want user to open the app OR mobile screen every time for location trace rather just start one time services and running as long as user don't click on clock Out.